# Scala table print

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala. I want to figure out a way to print a imuutable data which is a map with a key that is a tuple of strings and a value that is a double:

```
Map(
 ("ZZ1", "A") -> 3.5,
 ("ZZ2", "C") -> 2.3,
 ("ZZ3", "D") -> 2.8,
 ("ZZ1", "D") -> 3.0,
 ("ZZ2", "D") -> 5.9
)
```

The idea is to end up with a print similar to a table filled with zeros where there is no value (example in image below).

[image: table print]

How would be a possible way to perform this avoiding loops?

Thanks in advance

Comment: WHat do you mean by "avoiding loops"? Iterating over the (parts of) the keys is unavoidable, really (and the 'map' in the answers so far is a loop, really)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
val data = Map(
 ("ZZ1", "A") -> 3.5,
 ("ZZ2", "C") -> 2.3,
 ("ZZ3", "D") -> 2.8,
 ("ZZ1", "D") -> 3.0,
 ("ZZ2", "D") -> 5.9
)

val (rows, cols) = {
  val (r, c) = data.keys.unzip
  (r.toList.sorted, c.toList.sorted)
}

val table = 
  ("" +: cols).map("%5s".format(_)).mkString + "\n" +
  rows.map { r =>
    "%5s".format(r) + cols.map { c =>
      " %4.1f".format(data.getOrElse((r, c), 0.0))
    }
    .mkString
  }.mkString("\n")

println(table)
```

Gives:

```
         A    C    D
  ZZ1  3.5  0.0  3.0
  ZZ2  0.0  2.3  5.9
  ZZ3  0.0  0.0  2.8
```

I didn't try to make all the spaces look exactly as in the image, there are better tools for that (TeX, CSS).

Comment: Nice that it doesn't assume the values in the keys, but doesn't match the spec (no column B)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul What "spec"? Image of desired output does not count as "spec". If you want any column names that don't even appear in the input data, then you'll have to provide them explicitly - feel free to change the definitions of `rows` and `cols` to whatever you think is more interesting that the data that is actually stored in the variable `data` (just be prepared to see that entire columns will consists of boring zeros).

Answer (score 1):

Given your data structure, you can group by first column of a tuple and then manually extract the values as below.

You have one loop to group by(with inner loop to iterate though grouped values which means `O(n^2)`) and loop to iterate though each to print(`O(n)`).

```
val data = Map(("ZZ1", "A") -> 3.5,
               ("ZZ2", "C") -> 2.3,
               ("ZZ3", "D") -> 2.8,
               ("ZZ1", "D") -> 3.0,
               ("ZZ2", "D") -> 5.9)

val group = data.groupBy{case (k, v) => k._1}.map { case (k, v) =>
    k -> v.map { case (k1, v1) => k1._2 -> v1 }
}

val Separator = "     "
println(s"${Separator}A ${Separator}B${Separator}C${Separator}D")

group.foreach {case (k, v) =>
    println(
      k + " " + 
      v.get("A").getOrElse(0.0) + Separator + 
      v.get("B").getOrElse(0.0) + Separator + 
      v.get("C").getOrElse(0.0) + Separator + 
      v.get("D").getOrElse(0.0))
}
```

Result:

```
      A      B       C       D
ZZ1 3.5     0.0     0.0     3.0
ZZ3 0.0     0.0     0.0     2.8
ZZ2 0.0     0.0     2.3     5.9
```

Here's running example - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/ZaK6hk2gRbSd6Yq1op7N1Q